# How to fit a known linear equation to my data in R?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I used a linear model to obtain the best fit to my data, lm() function.
From literature I know that the optimal fit would be a linear regression with the slope = 1 and the intercept = 0. I would like to see how good this equation (y=x) fits my data? How do I proceed in order to find an R^2 as well as a p-value?

This is my data
(y = modelled, x = measured)

```
measured<-c(67.39369,28.73695,60.18499,49.32405,166.39318,222.29022,271.83573,241.72247, 368.46304,220.27018,169.92343,56.49579,38.18381,49.33753,130.91752,161.63536,294.14740,363.91029,358.32905,239.84112,129.65078,32.76462,30.13952,52.83656,67.35427,132.23034,366.87857,247.40125,273.19316,278.27902,123.24256,45.98363,83.50199,240.99459,266.95707,308.69814,228.34256,220.51319,83.97942,58.32171,57.93815,94.64370,264.78007,274.25863,245.72940,155.41777,77.45236,70.44223,104.22838,294.01645,312.42321,122.80831,41.65770,242.22661,300.07147,291.59902,230.54478,89.42498,55.81760,55.60525,111.64263,305.76432,264.27192,233.28214,192.75603,75.60803,63.75376)

modelled<-c(42.58318,71.64667,111.08853,67.06974,156.47303,240.41188,238.25893,196.42247,404.28974,138.73164,116.73998,55.21672,82.71556,64.27752,145.84891,133.67465,295.01014,335.25432,253.01847,166.69241,68.84971,26.03600,45.04720,75.56405,109.55975,202.57084,288.52887,140.58476,152.20510,153.99427,75.70720,92.56287,144.93923,335.90871,NA,264.25732,141.93407,122.80440,83.23812,42.18676,107.97732,123.96824,270.52620,388.93979,308.35117,100.79047,127.70644,91.23133,162.53323,NA ,276.46554,100.79440,81.10756,272.17680,387.28700,208.29715,152.91548,62.54459,31.98732,74.26625,115.50051,324.91248,210.14204,168.29598,157.30373,45.76027,76.07370)
```

Now I would like to see how good the equation y=x fits the data presented above (R^2 and p-value)?

I am very grateful if somebody can help me with this (basic) problem, as I found no answers to my question on stackoverflow?

Best regards Cyril

Comment: Run the `lm` examples provided by `?lm`.

Comment: I don't quite understand your suggestion. How do I run the lm examples and how do they help me find the fit of y=x?

Comment: @Cyril `lm` is the function for fitting linear model in R. As  the comment above says,  type `?lm` in R console or Rstudio to see the help for the function. Scroll to the bottom of help and you will see a basic example. It is very similar to your problem.

Comment: What is x? what is y? Please use consistent notation in your question.

Comment: y = modelled, x = measured

Comment: There is some question regarding the data presented in the question. If the undisclosed linear model has an intercept (does it?) then the sum of the residuals are zero but `sum(measured - modelled, na.rm = TRUE)` is far from 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's be clear what you are asking here. You have an existing model, which is "the `modelled` values are the expected value of the `measured` values", or in other words, `measured = modelled + e`, where `e` are the normally distributed residuals.

You say that the "optimal fit" should be a straight line with intercept 0 and slope 1, which is another way of saying the same thing.

The thing is, this "optimal fit" is *not* the optimal fit for your actual data, as we can easily see by doing:

```r
summary(lm(measured ~ modelled))
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = measured ~ modelled)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -103.328  -39.130   -4.881   40.428  114.829 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept) 23.09461   13.11026   1.762    0.083 .  
#> modelled     0.91143    0.07052  12.924   <2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 55.13 on 63 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.7261, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7218 
#> F-statistic:   167 on 1 and 63 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

This shows us the line that would produce the optimal fit to your data in terms of reducing the sum of the squared residuals.

But I guess what you are asking is "How well do my data fit the model `measured = modelled + e` ?"

Trying to coerce `lm` into giving you a fixed intercept and slope probably isn't the best way to answer this question. Remember, the p value for the slope only tells you whether the actual slope is significantly different from 0. The above model already confirms that. If you want to know the r-squared of `measured = modelled + e`, you just need to know the proportion of the variance of `measured` that is explained by `modelled`. In other words:

```r
1 - var(measured - modelled) / var(measured)
#> [1] 0.7192672
```

This is pretty close to the r squared from the `lm` call.

I think you have sufficient evidence to say that your data is consistent with the model `measured = modelled`, in that the slope in the `lm` model includes the value 1 within its 95% confidence interval, and the intercept contains the value 0 within its 95% confidence interval.

Comment: Hi Allan, the second part of variance explained is slightly off, because the degree of freedom in the fitted and observed is different (because of the NA in modeled).

Comment: What I am wondering is the interpretation of fitting a model of measured vs predicted, as you showed in the first lm() run. Why would you expect a coefficient of 1, especially when you fit a model with an intercept.

Comment: @StupidWolf you'd be right about the variance, although I had already excluded the  NA values from both vectors. I should have shown that explicitly in my answer. I wouldn't _expect_ a coefficient of 1, it's just that the OP stated that this _is_ the model. Fitting the model without an intercept is just a way of presupposing the result ("the intercept **is** zero). I think the question is really "are my modelled values consistent with my measured values?" and the answer is "yes". There are an infinite number of models consistent with the data. `measured = modelled + e` is one of them.

Comment: Ok good point. The larger question is not about R^2

Comment: This answer has multiple comparison issues leading to an incorrect conclusion.  Also the 0-1 model has no coefficients so R squared does not exist.  The other answer has the same problem with R squared.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck my reading of this is that the `modelled` numbers are actually the predictions from some undisclosed linear model. It would of course be far preferable to see the original model. But is it not still the case that one can estimate the proportion of variance of `measured` that could be accounted for by `modelled`? Certainly it gives a similar r-squared to a direct `lm` call. I accept that `y = x` is not the optimal fit, but I can't see any strong evidence to reject it either if there is good theoretical justification. I would be happy to be educated if I am wrong about this.

Comment: If `modelled` iand `measured` are the fitted and actual values of an undisclosed model and if the question is asking about that undisclosed model and not about `lm(y ~ x)` and is not about whether the submodel of `y~x` with intercept=0 and slope=1 fits then I agree that R squared can be calculated. Regarding a hypothesis test we would need the `lm` object of the original model (or at least its degrees of freedom).  However, the confidence interval argument is not valid in any case.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck fair enough. I guess I'm making a few assumptions about what the OP is asking, and I know that the confidence interval argument doesn't hold in view of the fitted slope. I guess my point is that having plotted the points, the lm and the y = x line as well as the residual histogram, I don't think there is enough evidence here to reject `y = x` as a model. You're right that the reasoning is flawed, but I still don't see why the conclusion is wrong as you asserted above (i.e.why you think `y = x` should be rejected). I'm keen to learn.

Comment: That comment was assuming that the question was whether intercept = 0 and slope = 1 in the lm(y ~ x) model.  If the question is about an undisclosed model then one can't perform the usual F test only with the information shown.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the `lm()` function, but this actually estimates the slope and intercept for you, whereas what you want is something different.

If slope = 1 and the intercept = 0, essentially you have a fit and your `modelled` is already the predicted value. You need the r-square from this fit. R squared is defined as:

> R2 = MSS/TSS = (TSS − RSS)/TSS

See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explained_sum_of_squares) for definition of RSS and TSS.

We can only work with observations that are complete (non NA). So we calculate each of them:

```
TSS = nonNA  = !is.na(modelled) & !is.na(measured) 
# residuals from your prediction
RSS = sum((modelled[nonNA] - measured[nonNA])^2,na.rm=T)
# total residuals from data
TSS = sum((measured[nonNA] - mean(measured[nonNA]))^2,na.rm=T)    

1 - RSS/TSS
[1] 0.7116585
```

Answer (score 1):

If `measured` and `modelled` are supposed to represent the actual and fitted values of an undisclosed model, as discussed in the comments below another answer, then if `fm` is the `lm` object for that undisclosed model then

```
summary(fm)
```

will show the R^2 and p value of that model.

The R squared value can actually be calculated using only `measured` and `modelled` but the formula is different if there is or is not an intercept in the undisclosed model.  The signs are that there is no intercept since if there were an intercept `sum(modelled - measured, an.rm = TRUE)` should be 0 but in fact it is far from it.

In any case R^2 and the p value are shown in the output of the summary(fm) where fm is the undisclosed linear model so there is no point in restricting the discussion to `measured` and `modelled` if you have the `lm` object of the undisclosed model.

For example, if the undisclosed model is the following then using the builtin `CO2` data frame:

```
fm <- lm(uptake ~ Type + conc, CO2)
summary(fm)
```

we have the this output where the last two lines show R squared and p value.

```
Call:
lm(formula = uptake ~ Type + conc, data = CO2)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-18.2145  -4.2549   0.5479   5.3048  12.9968 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      25.830052   1.579918  16.349  < 2e-16 ***
TypeMississippi -12.659524   1.544261  -8.198 3.06e-12 ***
conc              0.017731   0.002625   6.755 2.00e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 7.077 on 81 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5821,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5718 
F-statistic: 56.42 on 2 and 81 DF,  p-value: 4.498e-16
```