# How to fit a known linear equation to my data in R to get R2 and AIC

Tags: r, lm

I know the equation of a line I would like to fit to my x,y data and I wanted to compare its fit to the OLS model produced by `lm` for the same x,y data. Here is my reprex:

```
# data

dat<-structure(list(Q.x = c(26.25, 8.66, 6.4, 4.11, 5.95, 7.82, 2.75, 
1.36, 8.69, 11.16, 2.89, 1.21, 3.11, 7.11, 15.21, 2.41, 3.09, 
8.98, 2.72, 1.17, 4.5, 2.83, 2.6, 13.17, 2.33, 2.29, 2.08, 3.37, 
7.9, 3.11, 4.53, 4.7, 3.82, 4.81, 1.62, 3.96, 3.96, 2.92, 10.45, 
4.36), Q.y = c(8.47, 2.49, 1.27, 1.7, 1.35, 2.08, 0.72, 0.36, 
2.41, 3.06, 0.71, 0.25, 0.76, 1.55, 3.77, 0.46, 0.85, 1.15, 0.65, 
0.29, 0.96, 0.69, 0.75, 5.8, 0.62, 0.65, 0.45, 1.05, 1.81, 0.92, 
1.08, 0.86, 0.94, 1.19, 0.45, 0.96, 0.91, 0.85, 4.28, 1.67), 
    Q.DA = c(6.19, 2.04, 1.51, 0.97, 1.4, 1.84, 0.65, 0.32, 2.05, 
    2.63, 0.68, 0.28, 0.73, 1.68, 3.58, 0.57, 0.73, 2.12, 0.64, 
    0.27, 1.06, 0.67, 0.61, 3.1, 0.55, 0.54, 0.49, 0.79, 1.86, 
    0.73, 1.07, 1.11, 0.9, 1.13, 0.38, 0.93, 0.93, 0.69, 2.46, 
    1.03)), row.names = c(NA, 40L), class = "data.frame")

# OLS model to the x,y data

OLS<-lm(dat$Q.y~dat$Q.x)

# AIC for OLS model

AIC(OLS)

# plot of what I want:

plot(dat$Q.x, dat$Q.y)

abline(OLS)

points(dat$Q.x, dat$Q.DA, col = 'red')
```

The data in `dat$Q.DA` is the same as the data in `dat$Q.x` multiplied by a scaling factor (in this case the scaling factor is 0.2357143). Thus, the model I am trying to compare to the OLS model of the x,y data is also a line with the equation y = m*x + b, where y is `dat$Q.y` and x is `dat$Q.x`, yet instead of solving for m and b using OLS, m is the scaling factor, and b is 0. How would I determine how well this known line (line that falls along red points in plot) fits the data (black points in the plot) as compared to the OLS line (black line in plot)? My thinking is to use R-square and AIC.

This question was asked here: [How to fit a known linear equation to my data in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64620264/how-to-fit-a-known-linear-equation-to-my-data-in-r)

and in Allan Cameron's answer, he says that trying to coerce `lm` to a known slope and intercept isn't the best way to answer the OP question. However, my situation is different in that I want AIC in addition to R-squared, so my thinking is I need to coerce `lm` so I can get a model object for which to use `AIC()` on. Maybe the solution lies in a different approach (i.e. not using `lm`)? Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.